# VIM hardcopy print strange characters

Tags: vim

when I use VIM in my language - Hungarian -, when I want to print my buffer to a file, or just simply print it, then a few characters are strange. In VIM everything works and looks great, but using :hardcopy > print.pdf, it just brake.

I use Ubuntu 18.04, UTF-8 encoding in the terminal, and in VIM I use UTF-8. This issue only occurs when I use VIM hardcopy.

As I see **ő** and **ű** characters are broken.

Here is a screenshot about a broken part - see the yellow highlighted parts. Like an inverse question mark.

Could you help me on it?

I tried to use setfont=Ubuntu\ Mono:h10, but does not help.[image]

Comment: This might give you a starting point: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/12058/printing-unicode-chars

Comment: Nothing. I followed the instructions from there, and set encodings in my .vimrc. Now encoding=utf-8; fileencoding=utf-8; printencoding=utf-8; But hardcopy still replaces my ő ű characters with that strange downside questionmark. Its really strange, as I use unoconv, it works great. Using vim for editin, everything works great, if I use T0Html, it works great. When I use gedit to open and print the same file, works great. So looks like a bug in VIM.